# How to get item that has a specific class from set of elements and then count which number of the set of elements it is?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So it's hard to explain without giving an example, but I'll try my best.

So lets say my HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece active-piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I want is in Javascript/jQuery to get the `.active-piece`, then from there on count which `.item` it is inside of the `.container` element.(**So **2** being the answer, considering we start counting from 0**)

I know I can get the `$('.active-piece')`, and probably should get the parent of the parent from there but then what am I suppose to do?

Maybe I'm thinking too difficult, but I can't seem to figure out how to do get the expected result. Does anyone know how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to get index of the `item` element that has child element at some level with the class `active-piece`. To do that you could use `closest` method to get parent with class `item` and then get `index` of that element

```
$('.active-piece').closest('.item').index();
```

```js
const index = $('.active-piece').closest('.item').index();
console.log(index)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece active-piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I copied this and changed it to `$('.container .active-piece').closest('.item').index();` cause there may be multiple set of elements like this on the same page. however it returns -1. Do you know why?

Comment: In that case you should loop each `container` element and find the active one inside current container, something like this https://jsfiddle.net/84of1sqt/1/

Comment: Sorry thats not necessary. Cause this i the only element that's called  `.container` the other would be called `.container-2` etc.. I didnt make that clear. It's still giving me -1 though

Comment: Could you recreate an example in jsfiddle where its not working?

Comment: If you change the code in this snippet to `$('.container .active-piece').closest('.item').index()` then run it (in the snippet) it still works fine. The snippet uses the *same* HTML as provided in the question.  Therefore this answer correctly answers the question **as asked**. If it's not working for you then you *have not provided enough information **in the question**.*  Please update the question with enough information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes I can see the jsfiddle. It seems to go right here. I'll mark it as solved

Comment: To be clear, it doesn't preclude you from clarifying the question for your specific/live scenario, as asked above: *"Could you recreate an example in jsfiddle where its not working?"*.  We're here to help you get a solution after all.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes. I couldn't recreate an example in jsfiddle where it's not working. I just solved my other problem where it returned -1 for myself. It was because the `.item` was not rendered in yet when the `console.log` was called. So the problem was unrelated to this question, but I didn't know that when I used this solution for the first time.

Comment: @Loko Just to point out `index` method will return -1 if your jquery selector (that you called index method on) does not match any element.

Comment: @Loko glad you found a solution

Answer (score 1):

I know there are examples above, but they all use jQuery. So I've written a little bit about how to do this with vanilla javascript. It may not be the most optimal, but hopefully it helps if you don't wish to use jQuery. (I still recommend the jQuery methods if you already use it in your project)

So we start by finding the `.active-piece` element.

```js
var active = document.querySelector(".active-piece");
```

Next, we'll back up until we're in the `.item` element. We know it is two elements above.

```js
var item = active.parentElement.parentElement;
```

Now we'll loop through the parent of item until we find a match.

```js
for (var i=0; i < item.parentElement.childElementCount; i++) {
    var compare = item.parentElement.children.item(i);
    if (compare == item) {
        console.log(`index of item containing active-piece is ${i}`);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet

```js
var active = document.querySelector(".active-piece");

var item = active.parentElement.parentElement;

for (var i=0; i < item.parentElement.childElementCount; i++) {
    var compare = item.parentElement.children.item(i);
    if (compare == item) {
        console.log(`index of item containing active-piece is ${i}`);
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece active-piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet with OPs HTML so we can see it working?  (you could also do with a `break;` but it's no needed, just micro-optimisation)

Comment: I've added the snippet, thanks for the tip about break, I'll add it now

Comment: I see now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `filter` to get all the items having active-piece as child element,
you can store result in `itemWithActivePiece` variable and use it for further operations

```js
$(function(){
   var itemWithActivePiece = $('.container .item').filter(function(){
        return $(this).find('.piece-container .active-piece').length > 0;
   });
   console.log(itemWithActivePiece.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece active-piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="piece-container">
      <span class="piece"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```